# Selenium: Simulating human typing behavior

Tags: python, list, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to simulate human typing using Selenium and I've wrote a code for that, but I don't know how to continue it.

I want to make my code enter the 'thing1' element of lst into the variable `elem` webelement, and the second element of the list into the variable `elem2` webelement. Now, I don't know how do I do that. I've tried many ways but the code didn't work as it was supposed to. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

```
lst = ['thing1', 'thing2']
dt = webdriver.Firefox()
dt.get('some url')
elem = dt.find_element_by_id('some id')
elem2 = dt.find_element_by_id('some id 2')
#Breaking elements into keystrokes
for i in lst:
    for ii in i:
        time.sleep(random.randint(1.10))
        elem.send_keys(ii)
        #What to do from now on?
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you are entering both texts into `elem` element.

You may instead have pairs of element+text defined:

```
def human_type(element, text):
    for char in text:
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,10)) #fixed a . instead of a ,
        element.send_keys(char)


pairs = [(elem, "thing1"), (elem2, "thing2")]
for element, text in pairs:
    human_type(element, text)
```

You can also make that `pairs` list using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
lst = ['thing1', 'thing2']
elements = [elem, elem2]

pairs = zip(elements, lst)
```